# how echo this code <img class="comment-avatar pull-left" '

Tags: php, html, image

how echo this code  Already have tried to fix did not work

```
<img class="comment-avatar pull-left"    '.( !empty( $images[$count] ) ?  '<img  src="images/blog/'.$images[$count].'">' : '').'
```

Comment: how to echo what?

Comment: Do you mean you tried to echo this code you've posted but it didn't work? and what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  //$count = 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  //$images[$count] = '2';

echo '<img class="comment-avatar pull-left"'.( !empty( $images[$count] ) ?  ' src="images/blog/'.$images[$count].'">' : '');
```

you were missing a period.

Comment: need helppppppp